# How can I group by a table by the date?

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains:

```
  Name  / date
  test1  24-11-2014
  test2  24-11-2014
  teste3 23-11-2014
```

Im trying to make a query that count the number of names per date, But Its not working fine, it is returning 3 instead of 2.

My query:

```
  SELECT DATE(data),COUNT(data) as num FROM users 
  WHERE name = '$user' GROUP BY DATE(data)
```

How can I fix it?

THanks! Sorry for my english..

Comment: "it is returning 3 instead of 2" . . . ??? Your query returns two columns in each row.  What is it actually returning?

Comment: Im trying to count the different dates. There are 3 dates, but just 2 are differente

Comment: If you want to count dates, what does `names` have to do with anything?

Comment: I will make another question to explain my problem better, could u close this question please?

Comment: @MinearenaMine what is the datatype for this ? coz if it is datetime it will give the correct answer be group by

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the DATE() function you can simply do this, also you are counting names, not the dates

```
SELECT date,COUNT(name) as num FROM users 
  WHERE name = '$user' GROUP BY date
```

Also you are writing 'data' instead of 'date', what is the column name?

Comment: it istill not working, the table names are right. ):

Comment: are you still getting 3?

Comment: what is that user variable? and why are they different in the example if you have the contraint name='$user'?

Comment: The user variable is some name in the table, for example, if it is test1, num would return 1. But there are many names that are equals and diferrent dates.

Comment: Another thing i noticed is that your dates are in the wrong format, it should be YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Ohhh, my date is on this format d-m-Y. What should I do?

Comment: @MinearenaMine what is the datatype of your date column ?